# EventPattern handler is not being triggered outside controllers

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm trying to setup a [NestJS Hybrid Application](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application) that listens to a Redis service for events and triggers a handler in my code. I've defined a publisher that publishes events via `ClientProxy.emit()` as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics#publishing-events).

**EventPublisher.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class EventPublisher implements IEventPublisher {

  constructor(@Inject('redisClient') private client: ClientProxy) {}

  async publish<T extends IEvent = IEvent>(event: T) {
    
    await this.client.emit('a', JSON.stringify({event})).toPromise();
  }
}
```

I'm injecting my ClientProxy via my module class

```
const redisClient = ClientsModule.register([
  { name: 'redisClient', transport: Transport.REDIS, options: {
    url: 'redis://localhost:6379'}
  }
])

@Module({
  imports: [
    redisClient
  ],
  ... Other setups
})
export class FooModule {};
```

To listen to incoming events I created a microservice that uses redis as its transport.

**main.ts**

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());

  const redisMicroservice = app.connectMicroservice<RedisOptions>({
    transport: Transport.REDIS,
    options: {
      url: 'redis://localhost:6379'
    }
  })

  await app.startAllMicroservicesAsync();
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
```

This setup works fine as I am recieving the send data in my terminal when I subscirbe to 'a' using the redis-cli. I've tried defining eventhandlers on multiple classes in my code, but none of them are triggered when an event is emitted to  Redis unless I create a handler that is located in a controller.

**controller.ts**

```
  @EventPattern('a')
  doSomething() {
    console.log('success')
  }
```

In the documentation I can't find any mention of eventhandlers having to be in a controller, but that seems to be the only location that triggers the handlers right now. Would anyone know what could be causing this? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: So from trail and error it seems that the controllers are the only place a `@EventPattern` decorator seems to work. As for a reason why? I have not found any yet

Answer (score 1):

I came to the same realisation yesterday. I tried to look for an explanation in the documentation, but as often with NestJS, I found none. @Decorators make it hard to investigate as they hide their logic.

It seems indeed that `@EventPattern()` will only be triggered if placed inside a `@Controller()`, but I have yet to understand why.

Comment: Here's a small explanation. https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics#request-response